# CloudFlare force datacenter location in request

Tags: curl, cloudflare

I'm calling an API that is routed through CloudFlare.

```
curl -s 'https://binance.zendesk.com/api/v2/help_center/en-us/articles.json'
```

CloudFlare serves the response **from their closest datacenter**.

In my case the `curl` is running on a server in Amsterdam, Netherlands, so CF serves the response from their datacenter in Amsterdam.

---

**Question:**

How do I need to change the **request** to force Cloudflare to serve content **from a different datacenter**?

*Note: I don't have administrative access to the `binance.zendesk.com` CF account, so I'm looking for a way to force it in the request.*

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that this is done by the DNS server returning the IP address of the closest datacenter, you could specify the IP for the host manually:

```
curl --resolve binance.zendesk.com:443:104.16.53.111 -v 'https://binance.zendesk.com/api/v2/help_center/en-us/articles.json'
```

Comment: Thank you. But this still returns the header `cf-ray: 5479321f7ac3d90d-AMS` which means it's served from the Amsterdam datacenter.